# Highlighting VBA code in R markdown

Tags: r, vba, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a way to highlight VBA code in a R markdown code chunk e.g.

`{r, engine="vbnet", eval = FALSE}
Sub MyFirstSub()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub`

will not give the desired result (since vbnet is an unknown language engine).

`{r, eval = FALSE}
Sub MyFirstSub()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub`

partly work but I would like that e.g. the keyword Sub is highlighted also.

Comment: Unfortunately, pandoc (the engine that converts and provides the highlighting) does not yet support any of the VB variants (see [Pandoc's help page on syntax highlighting](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting)). There is one google hit on [adding a language](http://blog.jeci.fr/post/87994249356/adding-new-highlighting-language-into-pandoc), though I don't know if it is complete, up-to-date, or otherwise sufficient to help. Good luck.

Comment: Not good news. I was hoping though that you via knitr could add a few keywords for highlighting.

Comment: Pandoc uses [`highlighting-kate`](https://github.com/jgm/highlighting-kate) for the actual code highlighting; this uses syntax description files from [Kate's editor](https://kate-editor.org/), specifically [KatePart highlighting](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/katepart/highlight.html), so it should be possible to create an xml file for VB, VBA, VB.NET, etc. (Since Kate allegedly supports over 180 programming languages, it's possible that one of the VB variants is already supported, in which case send a request to @jgm to import it into `highlighting-kate`.)

Comment: NB: see a [previous discussion on adding more of Kate's languages](https://github.com/jgm/highlighting-kate/pull/1) (from 2010).